# What is the maximum slope for taxiing aircraft?

Tags: regulations, taxiing, airport-design

Every airport I have encountered has flat runways and taxiways.

Of course this is not exactly true, as some other questions picked up, and it is also possible that I just happened to visit mostly flat airports.

Is there any specification for maximum slope gradient an aircraft can safely taxi on?

A slope could be useful if an airport wanted to build an airplane bridge for example.

Comment: I suspect you've visited a limited (and perhaps rather boring) selection of airports.  Offhand, I recall Smiley Creek in Idaho and Alpine County in California as having noticable slopes.  Then there was Nevada Flyers north of Reno, where you generally approached at a 45 degree angle over a gravel pit, touched down on a downslope, then climbed a noticable hill followed by another downslope.

Comment: I suspect it wasn't with an A380 right ?

Comment: Nope, Piper Cherokee, mostly.  If you want answers that are limited to commercial passenger aircraft (in which I have very little interest), you should say so in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Footnote: I hope this is the correct/ current regulation. Published date is 25 January 2015.</sub>

Your question is covered (for EASA regulations) in the document *Certification Specifications and Guidance Material for Aerodromes Design* ([link](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/CS-ADR-DSN%20%20Issue%202%20to%20EDD%202015-001-R%20v1%20%28corrected%29.pdf)) in two sections:

- Taxiway Slope (CS ADR-DSN.D.265)
- Taxiway Slope changes (CS ADR-DSN.D.270)

> **CS ADR-DSN.D.265 Longitudinal slopes on taxiways**
>
> (a) The safety objective of limiting the longitudinal taxiway slope
>   is to enable stabilised safe use of taxiway by an aircraft.
>
> (b) The longitudinal slope of a taxiway should not exceed:
>
> 1. 1.5% where the code letter is C, D, E, or F; and
> 2. 3% where the code letter is A or B.
>
> **CS ADR-DSN.D.270 Longitudinal slope changes on taxiways**
>
> (a) The safety objective of limiting the longitudinal taxiway slope
>   changes is to avoid damage of aircraft and to enable safe use of
>   taxiway by an aircraft.
>
> (b) Where slope changes on a taxiway cannot be avoided, the transition
>   from one slope to another slope should be accomplished by a curved
>   surface with a rate of change not exceeding:
>
> 1. 1% per 30m (minimum radius of curvature of 3000m) where the code letter is C, D, E,or F; and
> 2. 1% per 25m (minimum radius of curvature of 2500m) where the code letter is A or B.
>
> (c) Where slope changes in (b)(1) and (2)  are not  achieved and
>   slopes on a taxiway cannot  be avoided, the  transition  from  one 
>   slope  to  another  slope  should  be  accomplished  by  a  curved 
>   surface  which  should allow the safe operation of all aircraft in all
>   weather conditions.

The letters refer to the [airport categorization](http://www.airfieldcharts.com/airportcategorisation.htm).

Comment: Good to see EASA being referenced!